# FOR EACH in phpmyadmin EVENT creation mysql

Tags: mysql, for-loop, events

here is my problem:

I would like to improve an event on my database which give every player 1 point.

That's great but i would like to do it proportionnally so that the players with like 20000 earn 0 points and the player with 10000 earn 50% less than the player with 0.

The formula is already made.

All i need is the for each and i can't do it because i'm not used to the events in phpmyadmin .

The [...] is the part i need help.

It is :

```
[FOR EACH ROW in player SET @id = playerid] 

        SET @points = SELECT points FROM player WHERE playerid = @id
        IF ( @points * 100 / 20000 > 100 )
        THEN 
            SET @earn = 0
        ELSE
            SET @pourcent = @points * 100 / 20000
            SET @pourcentmanque = 100 - @pourcent
            SET @earn = @pourcentmanque * 20 / 30
        END
        UPDATE player SET points = points + @earn WHERE playerid = @id

[END FOR]
```

Thank you for reading me and trying to help.

Comment: I'm not sure that you need a loop for this, you can use a `case` expression within an update as well. But do check out cursors.

Comment: a case expression ? for each % ? x) i'm not sure i understand :/


I tried with several exemples on internet i founded but every time it failed :(

Their exemples aren't made for the phpmyadmin event system.


If you have a cursor exemple that works with the phpmyadmin event system i would gladly try to adapt it :)

Comment: See the answers below. We both suggested the same thing: no loops, just a single update statement with a case expression. To get an example on using cursors, a quick google search will help you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply an UPDATE to many rows at a time.

The comment from Shadow suggested using a `case` expression. This is how it might look:

```
UPDATE player 
SET points = points + 
    CASE 
    WHEN points * 100 / 20000 > 100 
    THEN 0
    ELSE (100 - (points * 100 / 2000)) * 20 / 30
    END;
```

Notice there's no WHERE clause for a specific playerid. This means the UPDATE will be applied to all playerid's. The expression will use each respective player's current `points` in figuring how much to add.

Comment: yeah i thought that without the proper when with the id it would give a generic amount of points to every one several times x)

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you need a loop for this, simply use the `case` expression in the update statement without any where clause:

```
update players set points = points + (case
                                        when points*1/200>100 then 0
                                        else (100 - (points * 1/200)) * 2 / 3
                                      end)
```

I also removed some superfluous zeros from the calculation.

Comment: oh thank you ! i was certain that some command like this would like give 2000 to each player several times x)

Comment: If we solved the question for you, then accept one of the answers as solution, do not simply change the title.

Comment: ( the "superfluous" zero are for specific amount and time conversion in case i need to change the parameters )
the green check option wasn't avaliable yet . all i had was the favorite star . i changed the title so no one else would answer it for nothing ...
no need to be angry and giving me a bad reputation :(